# Question about dual-booting Windows and Ubuntu on 2 separate hard drives

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, windows, dual-boot

Hope you're all safe!

I have a question about dual-booting Windows and Ubuntu (or any Linux distro for that matter).

In my laptop, I currently have a 128GB SSD with Windows + core programs installed and a separate 1TB HDD with other personal data.

I want to dual-boot a Linux distro on my system (leaning towards Ubuntu at the moment, but also open to others), and I want to have the same setup as with Windows (i.e. core Linux + programs on my SSD and other data on my HDD), meaning I want to partition both the SSD and HDD into 2 pieces each.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Windows is probably UEFI, so be sure to install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode and use Something Else install option.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI  If a new user, put / (root) with 25 or 30GB on SSD and /home on HDD for as much space as you like.  Or if a bit more advanced or installing multiple Linux installs, use a /mnt/data partition, not /home as you cannot share /home but can share data.https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Answer (score 0):

Last time I installed ubuntu on a dual boot system, I simply checked the install alongside windows option. About the partitioning the hard drive, I believe that you can partition it in half, and then create a script to automatically unmount the windows half of the hard drive. This way, you would be left with half your ssd available for ubuntu and half your hdd available as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. After Windows installation with [Disk Management Tool](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-disk-management-2626080) remain on your SSD unallocated memory space.
2. Do the same for your hdd.
3. In progress of ubuntu installation select custom installation type ("something else" paragraph).
4. Map your home partition and / on hdd and ssd unallocated space accordingly.